# TypeScript mapped types: Flag type with nesting

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Is there a way in TypeScript to create a nested version of a `Flags` type mentioned in [Advanced types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) documentation?

This works well:

```
type Flags<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: boolean;
}

interface Colors {
  red: string;
  green: string;
  blue: string;
}

const activeColors: Flags<Colors> = {
  red: true,
  green: true,
  blue: false
}
```

But what if I wanted to create let's say a `NestedFlags` type that would be able to handle nested objects like this?

```
interface NestedColors {
  red: string;
  green: string;
  blue: string;
  more: {
    yellow: string;
    violet: string;
    black: string;
  }
}

const activeNestedColors: NestedFlags<NestedColors> {
  red: true,
  blue: false,
  green: true,
  more: {
    yellow: false,
    violet: true,
    black: true
  }
}
```

I am able to create a `NestedFlags` type with `[P in keyof T]: boolean | NestedFlags<T[P]>`. That solution works well except the fact that it allows me to create an object with eg. `more: false` which is undesirable in my case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want [mapped conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12424), which will be available starting in TypeScript v2.8, to be released sometime this month (March 2018).  You can use it now with `typescript@next`.  Here's a first shot at how I'd implement it:

```
type NestedFlags<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? NestedFlags<T[K]> : boolean
}
```

The above line uses the [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) ternary type syntax.  It means: for every key in `T`, the property type for `NestedFlags<T>` will depend on whether the original property is an object type or not.  If the original property is not an object type, the corresponding property will be boolean.  If the original property *is* an object type, then the corresponding property will be a `NestedFlags<>` applied to that object type.

This gives you the following behavior:

```
interface NestedColors {
  red: string;
  green: string;
  blue: string;
  more: {
    yellow: string;
    violet: string;
    black: string;
  }
}

// okay    
const activeNestedColors: NestedFlags<NestedColors> = {
  red: true,
  blue: false,
  green: true,
  more: {
    yellow: false,
    violet: true,
    black: true
  }
}

// error
const badActiveNestedColors: NestedFlags<NestedColors> = {
  red: true,
  blue: false,
  green: true,
  more: false
} 
// Types of property 'more' are incompatible.
// Type 'boolean' is not assignable to ...
```

TypeScript complains about `badActiveNestedColors`, saying that `more` should not be a `boolean`.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!