# Typescript object with conditional values based on key

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define a type for an object:

```
const width: Rule = {
  // regular keys with any name
  full: "100%",
  half: "50%",

  // special keys
  $px: [10, 50, 100],
  $rem: [1, 1.5, 2],
  $em: [1, 1.5, 2],
}
```

Where `Array<number>` value can only be used with special keys (`'$px' | '$em' | '$rem'`) and `string` value only with regular ones.

So I tried something like this:

```
export type Special = "$px" | "$em" | "$rem";

export type Rule<K extends string> = {
  [key: K]: K extends Special ? Array<number> : string;
}
```

But having an error at `[key: K]`:

> ```
> (parameter) key: K extends string
> An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.ts(1023)
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

The answer proposed in the comments doesn't work in my case, because I don't have a declared interface with known keys. I have a `Record<string, string | Array<number>>` instead and doing something like:

```
export type Rule = {
  [K in keyof Record<string, any>]: K extends Special ? Array<number> : string;
};
```

gives an error on special keys:

> ```
> (property) $px: number[]
> Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> ```

So far I ended up with something like this:

```
export type Rule = Record<string, string | Array<number>> & 
                   Partial<Record<Special, Array<number>>;
```

But obviously it allows to set `Array<number>` on regular keys which is not ideal.

Comment: The answer is mapped conditional types as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138332/typescript-mapped-types-flag-type-with-nesting). This question should be closed as a duplicate of that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript mapped types: Flag type with nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138332/typescript-mapped-types-flag-type-with-nesting)